# Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: mysql, ruby, database-connection

I am running a Rails app so now I am trying to remote connect to MySQL and I am getting this error:

> Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Comment: I was getting this sporadically while using the `parallel_tests` gem and I was able to reduce/fix it by increasing the values of both `max_connections` and `max_connect_errors` in my `my.cnf` file. Too early to say it's resolved but we'll see...

Answer (score 11):

You might want to check your */etc/hosts.deny* where:

```
ALL: ALL: DENY
```

or

```
mysqld: ALL: DENY
```

is your enemy.

Comment: This solved it. Was the last barrier after fixing my.cnf and forwarding 3306.

Comment: Add this to your /etc/hosts.allow to fix the problem:
mysqld: ALL

You may allow just clients coming from some network like this:
mysqld: 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

Comment: My god, you saved me.

Comment: Unfortunately for me I have no such file at this location. ```$ cat /etc/hosts.deny```
```cat: /etc/hosts.deny: No such file or directory```; I am on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: where is /etc/hosts.deny file in window?

Answer (score 8):

Rebooting the server worked for me. No settings changes needed.

Comment: Restarting MySQL worked for me. Don't know why this needs to be downvoted so much.

Comment: I agree with you since i'm noticing several upvotes as well as positive comments and of course in my case all i had to do was to restart mysqlserver

Comment: I'm upvoting both the answer as well as the comment since this was actually a fix for me

Comment: I've noticed rebooting does temporarily fix the symptom but it re-emerges.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a quick fix but it certainly doesn't solve the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

check from that host

```
shell> telnet IP 3306
```

If MySQL is up and reachable you'll see mysql version in telnet output.
Otherwise check firewall, etc until telnet succeeds.

Then I advice you first connect with native mysql client to exclude Rails from problem aria.

Comment: You should put real IP address instead of word "IP".
In my case I get a version and when I want to login from same machine it works properly but when I want to login from outside (like from other machine) I then get the exception as stated in top post.

Answer (score 4):

Enable remote access.

The MySQL server does not listen on the TCP port 3306 by default. To allow (remote) TCP connections, comment the following line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
skip-networking
```

Remember to edit `/etc/hosts.allow` by adding the following lines:

```
mysqld: ALL : ALLOW

mysqld-max: ALL : ALLOW
```

Comment: as of 2018-03-25 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.16: my file ```my.cnf```, which is not at the location here (I *think* it is at ```/usr/local/etc/my.cnf```), does not contain the line ```skip-networking```

Comment: 2018-03-25: GHOST: although creating a ``` /etc/hosts.allow``` appeared to work for me initially, then the symptom returned. (Rails 4.2.5 running Mac OS 10.12.6 using Capybara poltergeist phantomjs v 2.1.1)

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit your mysql Configuration file, by default the `bind-adress` is set to `127.0.0.1`.

Open: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Change the `bind-adress` to the ip you are going to use to connect yoursef to the database server.

Comment: same here.. didn't solve.. usually if i reboot the server it is back up and works again. checked `/etc/hosts.deny`, tried `127.0.0.1`, `localhost` and `liveserver-ip`...

Answer (score 3):

Using OS X? Does this issue go away for a while after mysqld restart and then re-appear? Check mysql server logs when getting these errors. I'm seeing a bunch of entries like below:

```
2019-01-30T17:34:04.009979Z 0 [Warning] File Descriptor 1564 exceeded FD_SETSIZE=1024
```

This error points to potential solutions:
https://expressionengine.com/blog/mysql-5.7-server-os-x-has-gone-away https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits/

One of them is adding following setting to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
table_open_cache=250
```

Comment: This is happening to me every day on OSX lately...  I'm tired of restarting it

Comment: @slashdottir It's still available from Google cache https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xoubmYu_otAJ:https://expressionengine.com/blog/mysql-5.7-server-os-x-has-gone-away+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pl&client=safari 
and there's at least one mirror https://pastebin.com/QwAysbYm

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqld-max: ALL : ALLOW
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

As we all know there are many different ways to install and configure mySQL dbms (database managment system) on our machines besides the fact we all run different OS (linux, osx, win$hit, etc)

In my case in particular i was getting

`connect': Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102 (Mysql2::Error)`

**BUT** i did not even had `/etc/hosts.deny` i only had `/etc/hosts` because i installed mySQL on my OSX machine using simple GUI OSX app

[image]
MySQL instance status was **NOT OK** above's image is just a reference for MySQL OSX APP.

Simple server re-start solved the issue.(in my case had to reboot my machine but that involves rebooting the MySQL server)

I was finally able to reach my localhost instance just fine again, did not had to change, create single file.

Hope this helps, i see [Malcolm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557956/malcolm)'s answer and comments and made me think it was good to post this.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has seemed to answer this, and it appears to have re-emerged as an issue nearly 7 years after originally being filed. I saw this on Rails app running Capybara (using phantomjs), my integration specs (only) would intermittently fail with this.

Restarting the machine temporarily fixed the problem.

I then imploded my MySQL installation completely (see https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x) and re-installed it using homebrew. The problem appears to have gone away but I will update this answer if it comes back.

to implode your MySQL install completely (from https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x):

Open a terminal window
Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text files!
Stop the database server

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
```

edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-

```
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

Answer (score 1):

**OS**: macOS

MySQL version: 5.7

Killed the current mysql service process

```
mysql.server stop
```

and started it again

```
mysql.server start
```

This solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your effort, I have found the solution, I was suppose to set Remote Connection to MySQLhere is the link for someone who got the same error 
http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/

Comment: stack overflow policy discourages answers by link; all answers are to be first-party answers