# C++ Program Calls PHP Script To Upload Content to Database

Tags: php, c++, mysql, database, network-programming

Say I have a C++ program that any user can download on their machine. I'd like to give the user the capability to upload content via this program to some remote database that I've set up.

My strategy is to have the C++ program call a PHP script that will connect to the database when prompted. However when I attempt to connect to a remote server that isn't localhost like the following call:

```
mysql_connect("website.com", "user", "pass");
```

It gives the error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial
communication packet', system error: 111
```

Is there some way to allow any user who downloads this program the ability to connect and upload content? Further more, is there a better way that could also work? Thanks.

Comment: sounds like the server is not set up for remote connections. could also be host port blocking. i hope you allow this user write access only.

Comment: Are the correct ports forwarded to from your website to the SQL server? Is your SQL server listening for a specific address? Have you looked further on stackover flow itself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961928/could-not-connect-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to directly upload from the user's machine why use PHP? Use the mysql C API. Just enable remote access in the mysql server.

But I won't advise to do that, it's better to have your own webserver, with it's "local" mysql, and then you won't have connection problems and expose your DB server to the outer world.

Comment: How would one enable remote access in the mysql server, and also what do you mean by the second statement?

Comment: 1) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges 2) what's your question?

Comment: 2.) Well I already have a webserver with its "local" mysql installed. However, I'm not sure how this prevents connection problems and does not expose the DB as I would assume users would have to connect to this machine as well correct?

Comment: set up mysql host-user-database privileges. set up iptables/mysql so only PHP can connect.

Comment: Are there any tutorials that you could recommend that go over implementing this? I apologize for my ignorance on the matter as this is relatively new territory for me. Thanks a lot for the prompt reply as well.

Comment: http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user