# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet' for remote mysql server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rake-task, dbconnection, database-connection

I am trying to access remote mysql database using rake task. Here i am posting my active record connection logic

```
client = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:host => "server_ip",
:port => 22,
:adapter  => "mysql2",
:pool => 5,
:database => "database_name",
:username => "username",
:password => "password"
)
```

I am accessing it using this

```
client.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
```

But every time it results with error as given below

```
rake aborted!
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Is there anything i am missing. Please suggest me right direction

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

Make sure MySQL connects from console with the same credentials

Make sure it connects in irb/rails console

If not, Add port number in the config you mentioned. MySQL should run in that port.

Check the access privilege for the username and IP in MySQL

Comment: It gives some active record object like #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00000...

Comment: access privilege are perfect as through browser i am able to access remote database

Comment: Adding port number in this it gives me error like this "Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0"

Comment: Check the host.allow and host.deny

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961928/could-not-connect-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communica