# Connection to Local Instance of MySQL from Remote Server

Tags: php, mysql

I have an IRC bot that collects some info and writes that info to a MySql DB. I run the IRC bot locally, and also an XAMPP server (latest version) for the MySQL locally (my PC).

I want to write this data to a remote mysql db as well. Unfortunately my FatCow hosting will not allow me to connect to my DB remotely.

So, I am trying to connect to the XAMPP setup on my local PC from a php page running on my FatCow hosting, but I can't figure it out.

I have changed the bind address to 0.0.0.0 ... I also have forwarded port 3306 on my firewall ... but I can't seem to connect.

I get this error: Message: mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

Thx for the help... I am a bit unfamiliar with this type of thing. Hand holding may be necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961928/could-not-connect-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communica)

Comment: I am not sure where to find the  /etc/hosts.deny ... adn cannot comment on other thread ... any help?

Answer (score 0):

Remote database connection is not supported in their shared hosting platform. So, it will not work.