# mysql - Mysql2::Error: [mysql_127.0.0.1:3306] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have been getting this error when I connect multiple processes to mysql in my local dev machine itself. Mine is:

1. Mac OS Sierra
2. Ruby on Rails

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/961928/2681997

Comment: I am asking for mac OS Sierra